# Sumar digitos de un número en Maxima

Tags: maxima

¿Cómo se definiría la función `sumaDigitos(n)` tal que `sumaDigitos` calcule la suma de todos los dígitos de un cierto número n?

Sé que en Python es así:

```
 sum(int(d) for d in str(n))
```

Por ejemplo,

```
sumaDigitos(1492) = 16
sumaDigitos(369870) = 33
```

He intentado hacer lo siguiente basandome en Python y en https://oeis.org/A007953:

```
sumaDigitos(n) := 
   if n<100  then floor(n/10) + mod(n,10)
   else round(9*(log10(n)+1))$
```

Pero, falla cuando el número es superior a 100.

Comment: y cual es el mensaje?

Comment: Si sabrían definirla de mejor forma que yo, lo cual no es complicado.

Comment: No veo en OEIS que `round(9*(log10(n)+1))$` sea para numeros mayores a 100

Comment: FORMULA  

a(n) <= 9(log_10(n)+1). - Stefan Steinerberger, Mar 24 2006      @lois6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas tu codigo, sale este return:

```
(%i1) sumaDigitos(n) := if n<100  then floor(n/10) + mod(n,10) else round(9*(log10(n)+1));
...
rat: replaced 1.0 by 1/1 = 1.0
(%o2)                      round(9 (log10(100) + 1))
(%i3)
```

Por lo que parece que algo de esa expresión `round(9 * (log10(100) + 1))` no lo está reconociendo.

[En el manual](http://www.johnlapeyre.com/qinf/qinf_html/maxima_html/maxima_14.html) pone:

> Maxima does not have a built-in function for the base 10 logarithm or other bases. `log10(x) := log(x) / log(10)` is a useful definition.

Traduccion:

> Maxima no tiene una funcion para los logaritmos en base 10 u otras bases. Usar `log10(x) := log(x) / log(10)` puede ser útil.

Asi que añadida esa funcion a tu codigo, el resultado ya aparece.

Pero no es el resultado de la suma de los digitos. Esa formula no creo que sirva. Por eso [te comentaba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143824/sumar-digitos-de-un-n%c3%bamero-en-maxima/143854#comment269239_143824) que no veia en OEIS que esa fuera para numeros mayores a 100 ...

---

Yo hice una funcion `sumDigitos` que crea un `stream` con el string del numero (para ello cojo el int y le concateno una cadena vacia `sconcat("",n)`)

Recorro el stream y para cada caracter, voy añadiendo al string `sum` un string `" + "` que sea la operacion de sumar digitos para que cuando acabe el while quede: `3 + 4 + 5 + 3 + 6`

Y despues uso `eval_string` para evaluar esa cadena suma y que de el resultado:

Codigo:

```
sumDigitos(n):=
    block(
        istream : make_string_input_stream(sconcat("",n)),
        sum:"",
        while (c : readchar(istream)) # false do 
            sum: sconcat(sum, "+", c),
        close(istream),
        eval_string(sum)    
    );
sumDigitos(34536);
```

Output:

```
(%o1) sumDigitos(n):=block(istream:make_string_input_stream(sconcat(,n)),sum:,while (c:readchar(istream))#false do sum:
sconcat(sum,"+",c),close(istream),eval_string(sum))
(%o2) 21
```